# Get notified if all files in Dropbox folder is older than 24h?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, webhooks, ifttt

I would like to get notified if there are no files newer than 24h in a specific Dropbox folder. IFTTT has a few Dropbox triggers, but they only trigger when new files are uploaded. So how could this be done? Do I have to use Dropbox's API and create something on my own? Or are there other services that can do this? IFTTT in combination with Dropbox's webhooks? All ideas are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you needed to create something on your own because most triggers are for when something happens, not for something that didn't happen. To create a trigger on your own, one approach would be to use a scheduled AWS Lambda function to periodically call the Dropbox API and then call a IFTTT (or Zapier, etc.) webhook if all files were older than 24h. Here's a link covering scheduled Lambda functions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html